# Ubuntu 14.10 can list Wi-Fi but won't connect

Tags: networking, wireless, 14.10, connection

I have Ubuntu installed on my SSD and moved it around to boot different PCs. I was using it on my laptop which has a builtin Broadcom card and it was working as expected. One day, it stopped working. Strange thing is, a couple days back Bluetooth stopped working too and I plugged a dongle to make it work. It was an old laptop and I removed the SSD and installed Windows 8. Both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth started working.

Then I put SSD back to my desktop and the Atheros AR9485 PCIe card which was working earlier would not connect either. The problem is same for both the laptop and the desktop. I can see SSIDs on the Network Manager widget but connecting doesn't work. It tries and gives up at the end.

Here's some hopefully useful info:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
  01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
  Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:3118]
  Kernel driver in use: ath9k
$ rfkill list all
  0: phy0: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
  1: hci0: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
$ dmesg | tail -n 20
  [  536.278326] wlan0: direct probe to 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 (try 1/3)
  [  536.480236] wlan0: direct probe to 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 (try 2/3)
  [  536.684206] wlan0: direct probe to 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 (try 3/3)
  [  536.888159] wlan0: authentication with 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 timed out
  [  547.642137] wlan0: authenticate with 14:b9:68:63:d6:80
  [  547.655433] wlan0: direct probe to 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 (try 1/3)
  [  547.857571] wlan0: direct probe to 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 (try 2/3)
  [  548.061490] wlan0: direct probe to 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 (try 3/3)
  [  548.265447] wlan0: authentication with 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 timed out
  [  783.833363] perf interrupt took too long (2508 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
  [ 1151.862130] wlan0: authenticate with 14:b9:68:63:d6:80
  [ 1151.875359] wlan0: direct probe to 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 (try 1/3)
  [ 1152.077243] wlan0: direct probe to 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 (try 2/3)
  [ 1152.281196] wlan0: direct probe to 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 (try 3/3)
  [ 1152.485033] wlan0: authentication with 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 timed out
  [ 1163.244460] wlan0: authenticate with 14:b9:68:63:d6:80
  [ 1163.257626] wlan0: direct probe to 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 (try 1/3)
  [ 1163.459545] wlan0: direct probe to 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 (try 2/3)
  [ 1163.663510] wlan0: direct probe to 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 (try 3/3)
  [ 1163.867406] wlan0: authentication with 14:b9:68:63:d6:80 timed out
```

Comment: I think your bluetooth issue will be gone when you get kernel 3.16.0-32 as long as you have the firmware downloaded with `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware`  With the older kernels there is a timing issue with the xhci_hcd and when ath3k wants to upload the firmware to the bluetooth device.  For me when I got the new kernel, it didn't work on the first power cycle but has worked since then

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there is a problem with the driver *ath9k* which has been fixed in later kernel versions. I suggest we install the *ath9k* driver suite from kernel version 3.19. With a working temporary internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.19-rc1/backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-3.19-rc1.tar.gz
cd backports-3.19-rc1
make defconfig-ath9k
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod -a
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

If Update Manager installs a later linux-image, after the requested reboot, you must recompile:

```
cd backports-3.19-rc1
make clean
make defconfig-ath9k
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod -a
```

Then reboot to load the newer driver.

You might also try a driver parameter:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
exit
```

Also, make sure your router is set to WPA2-AES and not TKIP. Reboot.

Comment: I tried it twice in case I missed something, but no dice. I hoped they'd fixed this issue by 3.19 release but maybe that wasn't it. Here's the dmesg: http://pastebin.com/0WsGLU4V

Comment: What the... http://pastebin.com/PWK95XC0

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Still no luck. :/ How do I see if I really got the newer version? Maybe the process's running into some invisible trouble?

Comment: Please try: `modinfo ath9k`. It sould report: "version:        backported from Linux (v3.19-rc1-0-g97bf6af) using backports v3.19-rc1-1-0-g74aaf28" Is that what you see? Does `dmesg | tail -n20` still read the same? Paste it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: modinfo outputs the same version string you wrote and yes, dmesg output is basically the same, see here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10576958/

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21864/discussion-between-frontsideair-and-chili555).

Comment: The problem is fixed by the way with the latest update. Weird.

Comment: Weird but good. Glad it's working.